# Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen "ist nicht zu verkaufen", "lässt sich nicht verkaufen" und "ist unverkäuflich"?

Tags: difference

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen diesen Sätzen?

- Das Bild ist nicht zu verkaufen.
- Das Bild lässt sich nicht verkaufen
- Das Bild ist unverkäuflich.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Das Bild ist nicht zu verkaufen.

Das Bild kann nicht verkauft werden, weil sich kein Käufer dafür findet, oder weil es gar nicht zum Verkauf angeboten wird.

> - Das Bild lässt sicht nicht verkaufen

Das Bild kann nicht verkauft werden, weil sich kein Käufer dafür findet.

> - Das Bild ist unverkäuflich.

Das Bild steht nicht zum Verkauf.

---

Disclaimer:
Das ist so aus dem Kontext gerissen nicht zu 100% richtig!

Comment: Je nach Kontext kann die erste Formulierung "(...) ist nicht zu verkaufen" entweder die Bedeutung "kein Käufer" oder aber auch "steht nicht zum Verkauf" haben. Letztere wäre IMHO sogar die etwas näherliegende Interpretation.